# Detecting vehicle on parking spot

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, automotive

For a project we're working on we need to detect if a car is standing on a parking spot.
We're using an ultrasonic sensor for this, [SRF05](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf05tech.htm). While using the correct timings we can only sense for about a range of 25cm. Even though the specs are saying a range of 3m should be possible.

How can we improve this range? Should we try another sensor? Suggestions please.

Comment: The ideal sensor is a coil of wire buried in the pavement, roughly car-sized, then you just look for a change in inductance.

Comment: Code would be needed to see why it's not responding right. Also have you tried another of the same type of sensor, maybe you broke it or it was DOA.

Comment: @NickT coil sensors are horrible in terms of repair. A ultrasonic or ir sensor or even camera in the curb or parking meter or light post are infinitely better in terms of a solution. Which is why visual sensors are used instead of coils for traffic turn lights in the last two decades (And because coils designed for metal cars don't trigger as well on mostly plastic cars, and almost never on motorcycles)

Comment: @Passerby Large inductive sensors could be used to monitor disabled spots. If the car doesn't have the appropriate RFID chip then the inductive power is increased until the signal disappears.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what? The inductive sensors Nick is talking about are metal detectors. What signal are you talking about?

Comment: @Passerby I was thinking of combining it with the inductive heating question. Kind of a joke.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany oh. Kinda hard to spot joke.

Comment: what about using a sensor with a more powerful ultrasonic emitter if range is the issue?

Comment: Seems odd you can only detect that short a range. How/where is it mounted? You say you are using correct timings, can you show us the numbers.